# Cassandra NoHostAvailableException

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have no problems when connecting to my cassandra 1.2.8 cluster inside of my local network by using Datastax Java driver. Out of my local network I get the NoHostAvailableException exception. I've checked 9160 port is up and mapped from router to the server. Could you help me with any other posible cause?

Thanks

Comment: is it a normal node or an AWS one???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Port 9160 is the default port for RPC connection (Thrift).

If you are using Datastax java driver, you should edit the **cassandra.yaml** config file and set

```
start_native_transport = true
native_transport_port = 9042 //Default port for CQL binary protocol
```

When bootstraping the cluster object for Datastax java driver, you should set port to 9042

Comment: you are right, I was mapping the wrong port (cassandra.yaml configuration was correctly set by default)